# h1 and nav element refuse to properly line up

Tags: html, css

I've looked through several questions regarding this already; however, none of them seem to solve or cover this problem.

What is essentially happening is that the h1 and nav element end up side by side but aren't properly lining up. I've tried multiple display and float settings on each but none are working.

The CSS itself is relatively clean, perhaps flex is not working properly or i am not using it properly? I'm not sure whats causing the problem here help is greatly appreciated!

```css
 /* Mobile CSS */
    #navbar h1 {
      display: block;
      padding-top: 1.4rem;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    #hbmenu {
      display: block;
      position:absolute; top:1.8rem; left:2rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
    }

    .iconbar {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 5px;
      height: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: #888;
    }

    #hbmenu:hover .iconbar {
      background-color: #fff
    }

    #navbar > nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: white;
      transform: 300ms all ease;
    }

    #navbar > nav > ul {
      margin: 0 auto;
      flex: 1;
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
     }

    #navbar > nav > ul > li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51,51,51,0.4);
    }

    #navbar > nav > ul > li > a {/*border bottom none?*/
     display: block;
     padding: 1.2rem 0;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 250ms all ease;
    }

    /* Medium screens or Desktop screens */
    @media all and (min-width: 600px) {

      #hbmenu {
       display: none;
      }

      #navbar h1 {
       display: inline-block;
       padding-left: 2rem;
      }

      #navbar > nav {
       display: inline-block;
       padding-top: 2.1rem;
       background-color: #333333;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul {
       padding-left: 1.8rem;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul > li {
       display: inline-block;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul > li > a {
         padding: 0 0.5rem;
         margin: 0 0.5rem;
         color: #9D9D9D;
         border-top: 1.5px solid transparent;
         border-bottom: 1.5px solid transparent;
         transition: 0.5s;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul > li > a:hover {
         border-bottom: 1.5px solid #fff;
         color: #fff;
         transition: 0.5s;
      }

    }

    /* Color & Font Stuff */
    #navbar > nav > ul > li > a {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .highlight {
     color: #9D9D9D;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .highlight:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<header>
     <div id="navbar">
      <button type="button" id="hbmenu">
      <span class="iconbar"></span>
      <span class="iconbar"></span>
      <span class="iconbar"></span>
     </button>
     <h1>
      <span class="highlight">Gatsby</span>
     </h1>
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </header>
```

Removing the h1 element allows to me properly add padding to the top of the nav element. While, having both only allows me to properly pad the h1. I'm sure padding isn't the best way to vertically center either but the problem remains.

UPDATE:

[misalignment picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV1Fq.png)

I quickly marked up the screenshot which hopefully clarifies the problem. The red line on the bottom demonstrates how the text currently lines up. While the red line on the top demonstrates how the li elements should be vertically centered.

[h1, nav element views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUOz2.png)

As this shows perhaps the bigger problem is how its currently setup as the elements don't "snap" if you will.

Comment: In what way are they not lining up?

Comment: Use the developer tools where you can see the margin and the padding. It might be different for the heading tags and the nav tags. That might be the issue

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlanPallath He is properly supplying his markup here. Fiddle's should only be used to compliment that, not be a source.

Comment: Your issue will lie in trying to line up disparate elements with different line heights and margins but trying to keep them 'inline'.

Comment: I could definitely get a fiddle up so the problem is more apparent and a screenshot so the actual misalignment can be seen, thanks for the help!

Comment: Updated with images as perhaps visually representing my problem/what I'm trying to achieve is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` elements can be vertically center aligned by using `vertical-align: middle;`, just add it to both `h1` and `nav`

```css
 /* Mobile CSS */
    #navbar h1 {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    #hbmenu {
      display: block;
      position:absolute; top:1.8rem; left:2rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
    }

    .iconbar {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 5px;
      height: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: #888;
    }

    #hbmenu:hover .iconbar {
      background-color: #fff
    }

    #navbar > nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: white;
      transform: 300ms all ease;
    }

    #navbar > nav > ul {
      margin: 0 auto;
      flex: 1;
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
     }

    #navbar > nav > ul > li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51,51,51,0.4);
    }

    #navbar > nav > ul > li > a {/*border bottom none?*/
     display: block;
     padding: 1.2rem 0;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 250ms all ease;
    }

    /* Medium screens or Desktop screens */
    @media all and (min-width: 600px) {

      #hbmenu {
       display: none;
      }

      #navbar h1 {
       display: inline-block;
       padding-left: 2rem;
       vertical-align: middle;
      }

      #navbar > nav {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;
       background-color: #333333;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul {
       padding-left: 1.8rem;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul > li {
       float: left;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul > li > a {
         padding: 0 0.5rem;
         margin: 0 0.5rem;
         color: #9D9D9D;
         border-top: 1.5px solid transparent;
         border-bottom: 1.5px solid transparent;
         transition: 0.5s;
      }

      #navbar > nav > ul > li > a:hover {
         border-bottom: 1.5px solid #fff;
         color: #fff;
         transition: 0.5s;
      }

    }

    /* Color & Font Stuff */
    #navbar > nav > ul > li > a {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .highlight {
     color: #9D9D9D;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .highlight:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<header>
     <div id="navbar">
      <button type="button" id="hbmenu">
      <span class="iconbar"></span>
      <span class="iconbar"></span>
      <span class="iconbar"></span>
     </button>
     <h1>
      <span class="highlight">Gatsby</span>
     </h1>
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </header>
```

Comment: In this case adding vertical-align: middle only to #navbar > nav. Then, changing #navbar > nav > ul > li to float: left instead of using display seems to produce proper behavior. If you want to update your answer I can make this the accept answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `flexbox` for your problem. Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/rzwxpr) sample. I think this was your requirement

```
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
  align-items: center;
}

h1, nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Check the [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/rzwxpr).

Comment: "I think this was your requirement" While your solution might be useful, it's basically a guess at what OP wants

Comment: @Abinthaha Quickly checking the codepen seems like you nailed exactly what I was trying to achieve. I will edit my project and accept this answer if it works.

Comment: @ovokuro I apologize if my verbal explanation was poor. I added pictures to help!